# Patterns in psychosomatic pains

Tags: psychiatry, pain, thought, emotional-intelligence

In the case of [somatoform disorders](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatic_symptom_disorder), when considering such a disorder where seeing the scenes of the surroundings and sensing a series of  psychosomatic pains in a specific way, is there a name for that type of somatoform disorder?

**Updated:**

For example, psychotic pains are such that, for example, during anxiety thoughts in the upper right region of the apadiancy or thoughts and emotions related to the affection of the pain in the heart area and ...

This situation is somehow associated with repressive mechanisms and in some way when there is no possibility of feeling emotionally or there is a lot of work. Some psychologist said to me about [Conversion disorder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_disorder).